rust polars dataframe shuffle
There is an argument named shffule in the function sample_frac (https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/frame/struct.DataFrame.html#method.sample_frac). As the indexes are created randomly, why do we need this argument ?
When will we need to use shuffle ?
pub fn sample_frac(
    &self,
    frac: &Series,
    with_replacement: bool,
    shuffle: bool,
    seed: Option<u64>,
) -> Result<DataFrame, PolarsError>


If set to True, the order of the sampled rows will be shuffled. If set to False (default), the order of the returned rows will be neither stable nor fully random.

I still don't fully understand that. Why are the returned rows neither stable nor fully random ?  what does 'stable' mean ?
